# Simple Iteration Covergence

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

A possible simple iteration rearrangement of the equation f (x) = 0 is in
the form x = g(x) where g(x) = x − k(f(x)/f'(x)) and k is some real number.

Determine the values of the parameter k for which this simple iteration
rearrangement is convergent, when finding the root of x^5 − 3x + 1 = 0
near x = 1.2.

Suggest a value of k that, in theory, should give the fastest
rate of convergence.

What do I do here? Is this linear or quadratic convergence?
Do I use this formula: |a-x_(n+1)|<= k|a-x_n|^p